# ImportError: No module named xxx after setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I've installed the google adwords API using :

> python setup.py build install

However, when I load python and try and import one of the modules I get the following:

> ```
> from oauth2client import client
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named oauth2client

or

> ```
> from adspygoogle import AdWordsClient
> ```
>
> ImportError: cannot import name AdWordsClient

How do I fix this?

Comment: What Python version are you using ? Maybe you installed the library for Python 3 and your script runs under Python 2 which doesn't share its libraries with Python 3. Edit: does it work when you install it with `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: Using python 2...setup.py install doesnt work either.

Comment: What happens with `from adspygoogle.adwords import AdWordsClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oauth2client library makes it easy to connect to resources protected by OAuth 2.0. The oauth2client library comes as part of the google-api-python-client, but is also available as a separate download if you just need the OAuth 2.0 capabilities.

The library supports these Python environments:

Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7
Google App Engine
Django

Comment: I cant seem to import any module...I've included another example.